# Android: How to find fragment container id

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my case I want to move from one fragment to other fragment. This should be done when i click the ListView. So I have written the fragment transaction code in onItemClick. But I don't know, how to find my container id for the fragment where i have to move.

Here is my code.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment fragment = new MeetingFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.MEETING, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

    });
```

I want to move to MeetingFragment. What id I have to give in this fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.--------, fragment) line. Please give an idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want to use FragmentTransaction.replace? maybe you should just startActivity insted?

Comment: have u tried android.R.id.content?

Comment: I think you have implement one interface in activity with callback when item click and try to replace your new fragment code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you define a Layout. For example

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Suppose I want to change fragments in the Framelayout whos id is 'content_frame' as shown above.

Then the corresponding code will be

```
      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,new newFragment());
      fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Where newFragment is the fragment that you want to move in.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity holding the fragments may contain a layout-ID to which we have to add our fragments.

for example my Activity holding fragmets have
 `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentgroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
         >
    </LinearLayout>`

you have to specify R.id.fragmentgroup in this case. the ID is of the layout to which we have to place our fragment